# apply payments to specific quickbooks invoice using Ruby Gem

Tags: quickbooks-online

Our ruby gem creates invoices in quickbooks, and then creates payments for the same amount and date. How do we have the payment apply to the invoice? (quickbooks online)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Payment doc.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/payment

It will be through Line( and linkedTran ) attribute.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/0700_other_topics#Line

Ex -

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-07-18T09:52:33.800-07:00">
    <QueryResponse startPosition="1" maxResults="1">
        <Payment domain="QBO" sparse="false">
            <Id>6</Id>
            <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
            <MetaData>
                <CreateTime>2014-07-18T09:51:59-07:00</CreateTime>
                <LastUpdatedTime>2014-07-18T09:51:59-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
            </MetaData>
            <TxnDate>2014-07-18</TxnDate>
            <CurrencyRef name="United States Dollar">USD</CurrencyRef>
            <Line>
                <Amount>300.00</Amount>
                <LinkedTxn>
                    <TxnId>1</TxnId>
                    <TxnType>Invoice</TxnType>
                </LinkedTxn>
            </Line>
            <CustomerRef name="Anna  Ellixson">2</CustomerRef>
            <DepositToAccountRef>4</DepositToAccountRef>
            <TotalAmt>300.00</TotalAmt>
            <UnappliedAmt>0</UnappliedAmt>
            <ProcessPayment>false</ProcessPayment>
        </Payment>
    </QueryResponse>
</IntuitResponse>
```

To get the correct object structure, create an invoice in QB UI and corresponding Payment and then retrieve the Payment Object using getById(Payment) endpoint.

You can try this from ApiExplorer.

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

Thanks